# How do I set a non existing field a default value in mySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that reads three fields from two different tables. The query is as follows :

```
SELECT t1.operation_number,t1.operation_description, t2.operation_checked 
FROM wla_prod.operations t1 
LEFT JOIN wla_prod.operation_technology t2 
ON t2.operation_technology_key = (SELECT t3.prod_technology_key FROM wla_prod.product_technology t3 WHERE prod_technology_name = @prod_name) ORDER BY t1.operation_number;
```

The output of the query is as follows :

```
Oper   |Desc  | Chcked
850474 |PS FM | 1
852191 |PDI   | 1
```

There is one record (850474) in t2 table. There is no record for 852191 in t2 table. However, when I read the table, I get 1 for operation 852191. I want the output to show 0 if there is no record in the t2 table. My query reads the last read value from t2 table field 'chcked'. How do I do that ?

Comment: `There is no record for 852191 in t2 table` ... your output implies the opposite, as the `Chcked` field is 1 for this record.

Comment: I agree with Tim. It's possible there's a problem with your join. Try `select t1.*, t2.*` to verify your join. What is the intent of the join and bringing in a 3rd table in the subselect?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/OJvhwUhW - you aren't joining on a relationship between operations and operation_technology , I am surprised mysql allows this but the query does not fail perhaps @Tim Biegeleisen could have a look and suggest why mysql produces the resultit does.

Comment: Also please add sample data for all 3 tables and the statement which sets @prod_name.